# Hardhat test is not working

Tags: hardhat, testing, chai

I try to run a simple test in Hardhat but for some reason it is not working it always returns:

```
0 passing (1ms)
```

This is the test:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { expect, assert } = require("chai")

describe("SimpleStorage", async function () {
  let simpleStorageFactory, simpleStorage
  beforEach(async function () {
    simpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")
    simpleStorage = await simpleStorageFactory.deploy()
  })

  it("Should start with a favorite number of 0", async function () {
    const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
    const expectedValue = "0"

    assert.equal(currentValue.toString(), expectedValue)
  })
})
```

When I run:

```
yarn hardhat test
```

it returns 0.
As if the test file is empty

```
0 passing (1ms)
```

This is hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("./tasks/block_number")
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")

const RINKEBY_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 4,
    },
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",

      chainId: 31337,
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.8",
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hardhat-simple-ss-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/abi": "^5.4.7",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.4.7",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.2",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^1.0.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.1.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.10.1",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-dev.23",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.21",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

All packages seem to be installed as in
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/other-guides/waffle-testing

What could be the problem?

Comment: what's your folder structure / name of the file.  It has to be in the "test" folder

Comment: it is in the "test" folder

Comment: @PinPiguin consider using my [Hardhat-based template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) so you don't have to configure this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your  beforEach(async function () is missing an "e" at the end of befor**e**

Should be beforeEach(async function ()

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have the `async` included in the top level describe block. Removing it should allow your tests to be executed. Replacing line 4 with this should solve your issue:

```
describe("SimpleStorage", function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test file need to be in the test folder, I ran into the same problem and all i had to do was move my test file which i mistakenly created in the root folder to the test folder. That will solve the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/97389)